# Why do I receive a length Mismatch error when collecting stats on two dataframes with derived data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes together to create a derived dataframe, but I am receiving a length mismatch error when I run my code.

DataFrame #1 (DF1) contains data for all email addresses that I have collected. There is only one column and X amount of records(see below).

```
   sender            
    0  c@aol.com         
    1  g@aol.com        
    2  b@aol.com         
    3  a@aol.com
```

Dataframe #2 consists of data that was collected from another system that holds data of all the emails that have been sent out in the system. This dataframe has 2 columns- sender, _time.(see below)

```
    sender        type          _time
0  c@aol.com      email   2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
1  c@aol.com      email    2020-13-09 19:45:48.013140
2  g@aol.com      email   2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
3  b@aol.com      email    2020-14-11 19:45:48.013140
```

I want to merge the two dfs together to create a third dataframe that collects stats on the number of times senders in DF1 were found in DF2; as well as the min and max time for each sender that is more than 1. As you can see in df2, c@aol.com has two different timestamps because they're two different records.
This dataframe will have 3 columns- sender, count, first_seen, last_seen. (see below)

```
      sender  count               first_seen            last_seen
0  c@aol.com   2          2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140   2020-13-09 19:45:48.013140
1  g@aol.com   1          2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140   2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140
2  b@aol.com   1           2020-14-11 19:45:48.013140   2020-14-11 19:45:48.013140
3  a@aol.com   0                     NA                     NA
```

**Here is my code so far:**

```
import pandas as pd
#Collect list of email addresses I want to find in df2
email_list = ['c@aol.com','g@aol.com','b@aol.com','a@aol.com']

# Turn email list into a dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame(email_list, columns=['sender'])

# Collect the table that holds the dictionary of emails sent
email_result_dict = {'sender': ['c@aol.com','c@aol.com','g@aol.com','b@aol.com',], 'type': ['email','email','email','email'], '_time': [' 2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140','2020-13-09 19:45:48.013140','2020-12-09 19:45:48.013140','2020-14-09 19:45:48.013140']}

# Turn dictionary into dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(email_result_dict)

# Calculate stats
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
res = df.groupby(['sender']).agg(['min', 'max', 'count']).reset_index()
res.columns = res.columns.droplevel()
res.columns = ['sender', 'count', 'first_seen', 'last_seen']
res.to_csv(r'output1.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

**Here is the error I am receiving:**

[image]

Any idea of why this error is being raised or a solution to fix my code to overcome this error? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error on this line (which has nothing to do with the merging)

```py
res.columns = ['sender', 'count', 'first_seen', 'last_seen']
```

because you are trying to rename 4 columns in a dataframe that has more columns than that. You need to rename every column.
I'd suggest printing out `df` after the merging to make sure you get the correct dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly spot on. It is expecting names for 7 elements, but you are providing 4 names.

Illustrating with your code, you are giving 4 names for the columns:

```
res.columns = ['sender', 'count', 'first_seen', 'last_seen',]
len(['sender', 'count', 'first_seen', 'last_seen',])
Out[63]: 4
```

But your res `dataframe` has 7 columns.

```
len(res.columns.tolist())
Out[62]: 7
```